# Touches on UILabel

Tags: iphone

In my program labels didnt detect touches while i testig on simulator. but it works fine on device. why does this happens?. i want to capture the video of my application when working on simulator.

Comment: You're not trying to touch the simulator on the screen with your finger are you;) Doesn't sound right at all. If there are no errors, might want to reinstall iPhone sdk .

Answer (score 1):

If you need a quick workaround for recording video, just put a clear UIButton over top of the label that calls the same function upon tap.